# Converting an arbitrary drawing into an interactive map?

Tags: flash, charts, mapping, geospatial, data-visualization

I have a floor plan of a building in PDF that I want to visualize as a map, using tools like [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/), [FusionMaps](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/), or [AmMap](http://www.ammap.com/). I am willing to redraw the floor plan if needed.

1. What format should the map data be in?
2. What kind of tool can I use to create that data?

Comment: You might check out: MapSVG [ http://codecanyon.net/item/mapsvg-interactive-vector-maps-and-floorplans/2547255 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've arrived at is to not use geographical data, but instead to draw the map in something like Illustrator, save as SVG, and then use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) to create the visualization.

There are a couple of example here:

[http://return-true.com/2011/06/using-raphaeljs-to-create-a-map/](http://return-true.com/2011/06/using-raphaeljs-to-create-a-map)
http://playground.mobily.pl/tutorials/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, none of those tools will be well-suited to visualizing floor plans. They're for broader geography. I'm not familiar with architecture applications, but I'm sure many exist for doing what you want to do. If I had to do in a geography-type application, I would probably create the floor plan in ArcGIS or QGIS and export as a .shp or .svg file. Google Sketchup may also be ideal from drawing and visualizing the floor plan.

Answer (score 0):

I would export the PDF to a large image format, then I would use a tool like the

GMapImageCutter - http://www.bartlett.ucl.ac.uk/casa/latest/software/gmap-image-cutter

MapTiler - http://www.maptiler.org/

To slice the image into tiles. Once that is done then upload the tiles on your server.

You could then use Google Maps, Yahoo Maps, Microsoft VirtualEarth, etc to view the tile as a custom map.

Personally I would recommend using V3 of the Google Maps Api to display the tiles. The great thing here is that you don't have to have a 'wrap around' map. That is, the image need not wrap north/south or east/west, which is ideal for a floor plan.

If any markers are required on the resulting Maps, these can be added very easily, and these 
markers can link to other maps. So things like stairs, lifts, etc, can be navigable points.

Here is an example using GMapImageCutter to display a HI-RES composite photo I took.

http://www.msa.mmu.ac.uk/~fraser/roof/